# If I have a Schengen visa but not stamped in Paris, can I travel to Mexico?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, mexico

If I have a Schengen visa but not stamped in Paris, can I travel to Mexico?

Comment: @aBochur you have apparently missed that Mexico exempts people from the visa requirement if they hold certain visas from other jurisdictions, including Schengen.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a valid Schengen visa, you do not need a visa to travel to Mexico as an Indian citizen:

> Holders of any valid U.S.A., Canada, United Kingdom and Schengen visas (any nationality) DO NOT require a Mexican visa to travel on business, tourism or transit purposes only. The length of stay shall not exceed 180 days.

Source: https://embamex.sre.gob.mx/india/index.php/visas

The fact that your Schengen visa is not used yet does not affect its validity.